# Visual Studio doesn't load project references

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-10, csproj

I have a Visual Studio (Community 2013) solution with many c# projects on my pc and I've just upgraded to Windows 10 from 7. The project uses .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile. On win7 everything worked fine, but now one of the projects doesn't seems to load references. There are yellow triangles near the referenced items, what are not items referenced from the same solution (so system and references downloaded by NuGet not loaded).

[image: references...]

The *Resources* is another project in the solution, the others not. When I open the properties tab for a system reference, the `Path` field is empty, and so the `Resolved` field is `False`...

[image: empty path]

Besides, in the .csproj file everything seems to be ok, there are `<HintPath>` nodes where needed, with relative (or absolute, if the reference is on another drive), and correct, existing paths.
Another weird thing: in the Object Browser all of the references are (seemingly) loaded:

[image: Object Browser seems to be ok]

So, what should I do:

- re-create the project file (by creating new project and add all files and references again);
- change something in the configuration of the project;
- use a newer version of .Net;
- change something in the configuration of VS;
- use another VS (eg. Community 2015) or reinstall the current one?

Comment: Have the framework installed? You might be absent 4.0 given 4.5.x is latest and I doubt windows 10 includes older frameworks. And you may be observing the libraries for a newer framework in class explorer, but (because of the version difference) won't be included in your project.

Comment: @BradChristie I tried to reinstall the framework, but it exits saying "the microsoft net framework 4 is the part of this operating system..." (etc). The other projects can load their references correctly, they uses the same framework.

Comment: Framework,  or sdk framework?

Comment: Other projects with the same target framework don't have this issue, so I probably have sdk framework...

Comment: Have you tried dropping and readding references one by one?

Comment: Looks like you lost the c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies directory.  Not good.  Reinstalling VS would be one way to get it back.

Comment: @BradChristie Yes, I tried. No effect :/

Comment: @HansPassant The directory exists, but as I mentioned other projects with **exactly the same** configuration don't have the same problems, just this poor devil project...

Comment: Could you please attach the `*.cproj` ?

Comment: We have been seeing this at work as well. Projects created in Windows 8 or 7 load fine on 8 or 7, but on windows 10 the references don't load. Have not found a solution yet, but you are not alone.

Comment: I've seen the same issue with resolving references, leading to the same icon on project references, when someone tries to reference project B from project A, and project B has a higher framework version than project A. For instance, B is 4.6.1, and A is 4.5.2.

Comment: Question is misleading. VS is complaining about (assembly) references, not project references, which are different types of references.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I also had this problem and it took me some time to figure it out. The problem is that NuGet changed how the packages are restored. The "old way" needed the ".nuget" folder with 3 files (nuget.config, nuget.exe, nuget.targets) and some settings in the project file like:

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

This caused the project to be broken.

**To fix this**, copy the missing directory to the project (get it with an older version of Visual Studio/NuGet or from a co-worker who has it) or just simply delete the aforementioned part from the project file.

For best results, also remove:

```
<RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
```

and

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
```

from the project file!

---

Find more on the subject here:

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/troubleshooting-broken-references

Comment: I can confirm that this is the correct approach - assuming that the target framework was not your issue.

Comment: Wow, what a mess Microsoft has on their hands. In VS2017, apparently, this is still an issue. I struggled with this for 2 hours. 

When I finally read this post and copied the .nuget folder from another project into the solution folder, everything finally worked. Thank you!!

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot. Saved my day.

Comment: I had a very similiar issue.  My colleague added a project to our solution.  I updated from source control and on my pc none of the reference worked.  I couldn't quite understand Uszkai's solution, but they led me down a path to a similiar solution.  I opened the Nuget Package manager (from VS -> Tools).  I downgraded my "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" nuget package from version 2.0.1 to 2.0.0.  That fixed the issue.  I upgraded back to 2.0.1 and everything seems to be working well!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure both projects are targeting same framework version. For ex:one with the target framework .Net Framework 4.5.1 will not work with 4.5

Comment: OMG, I spent 2h on this one. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is the FRAMEWORK reference.

Load your project into VS and change it in your PROJECT PROPERTIES page (TARGET FRAMEWORK), upgrading to .NET 4.x (not client) or .NET 4.5

Comment: I tried, nothing better... Anyway other projects has no problems with that version of .Net.

Comment: I had this same issue, hundreds of such errors, after messing with it for hours realized, at the bottom of the errors was an indication of a non-existant file (or a coding error in a file), once resolved, these errors went away

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "TFS", or any other versioning system this way I have solved the issue:

Compare the solution file with latest. I did this and realized visual studio has added a lot configurations itself for x86 and that caused the issue even I try to get a build with x64. Checking out file then undoing the changes did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue in VS-2015(project was not loading references) when I moved the project to another folder.
And the name of the new folder was big, I shortened the name, and reloaded project then it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Here is what it resolved for me.
In the Visual Studio do below steps,

1. Build --> Clean Solution
2. Build --> Rebuild Solution.

This created the package folder inside my solution directory containing all required references and resolved the Project references successfully.